# How to use Google Calendar in the aspx using Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, api, google-calendar-api

I want to use the Google Calendar in my webform.aspx using Visual Basic. However, the only thing I know is I have to use the Google Calendar API. I tried to read [the instructions](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#setup) but I did not understand it. Like the example for .Net it uses `using Google.Apis.Authentication;` which I thought it should use `import` instead.

Show me how a google calendar can be use in a webform.aspx using vb

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the `using Google.Apis.Authentication;` statement, this is C# syntax.

The VB.Net equivalent would be `Imports Google.Apis.Authentication` as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Imports` statement instead of `using` which is a c# syntax. I would suggest if you cannot translate from c# to vb.net to use [this wonderful free tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) that can do that for you. I checked the Sample Google code and I do not see a vb.net version of it.

Good luck!